# Unable to get regex in python to match pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to pull out a number from a copy of an HTML page which I got from using urllib.request

I've tried a few different patterns in regex but keep getting none as the output so I'm clearly not formatting the pattern correctly but can't get it to work

Below is a small part of the HTML I have in the string

```
</ul>\n        \n        <p>* * * * *</p>\n        -->\n        \n        <b>DistroWatch database summary</b><br/>\n        <ul>\n        <li>Number of <a href="search.php?status=All">all distributions</a> in the database: 926<br/>\n        <li>Number of <a href="search.php?status=Active">
```

I'm trying to just get the 926 out of the string and my code is below and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
import urllib.request
import re

page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://distrowatch.com/weekly.php?issue=current')

#print(page.read())
print(page.read())

pageString = str(page.read())
#print(pageString)
DistroCount = re.search('^all distributions</a> in the database: ....<br/>\n$', pageString)

print(DistroCount)
```

any help, pointers or resource suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: Try this: `all distributions</a> in the database: (\d{3})<br/>` and `print(DistroCount.group(1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to convert HTML to text, and then apply a simple regex to extract a number after a hardcoded string:

```py
import urllib.request, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = urllib.request.urlopen('http://distrowatch.com/weekly.php?issue=current')
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
text = soup.get_text()
m = re.search(r'all distributions in the database:\s*(\d+)', text)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))

# => 926
```

Here,

- `soup.get_text()` converts HTML to plain text and keeps it in the `text` variable
- The `all distributions in the database:\s*(\d+)` regex matches `all distributions in the database:`, then zero or more whitespace chars and then captures into Group 1 any one or more digits (with `(\d+)`)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are reading the whole document into a single string, but use "^" at beginning of your regex and "$" at the end, so the regex will only match the entire string.

Either drop ^ and $ (and \n as well…), or process your document line by line.